# Fancybox success function close() is not working in ajax

Tags: jquery, ajax, fancybox

### **index.php**

```
 jQuery(function ($) {
      $("a.edit").fancybox();
 });


<a class="edit" href="showForm.php?id=<?=$row['id']?>"> Edit </a>
```

---

### **showForm.php**

```
$id = $_GET['id'];

jQuery(function ($) {
$('#btnSend').click(function(){

        var key = $('input:hidden[name=id]').val();

        $.ajax({
                url: "process.php", 
                type: "POST",
                data: { "something": "something", "id": key}, 
                success: function(response) {
                    // I'm sure do something can work //

                    $.fancybox.close();  //this not work!
                    // parent.$.fancybox.close(); // or this
                }
        }); 
    });
});


<body>  
   *edit something...*

   <input type="hidden" name="id" value="<?=$id?>">
   <input type="button" id="btnSend" value=" Submit ">
</body>
```

---

### **process.php**

```
$id = $_POST['id']; 
$something = $_POST['something'];

$sql = "UPDATE db 
        SET 
        something           =   '{$something}',
        WHERE id = '{$id}' ";
$result = $mysql->query($sql);
```

I can update my data, but 
 **$.fancybox.close();** 
**jQuery.fancybox.close();** 
**parent.$.fancybox.close();** 
all can't work...

version: fancybox-1.3.4

PS: when I use Ajax to submit form in samepage(index.php) , the **$.fancybox.close();** can work!

Comment: what does log show? any errors?

Comment: are you getting a success response?

Comment: @vladkras **Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'is' of undefined**

Comment: @JanR **success: function(response) { alert('TEST'); // it can work }**

Comment: @Gondola what version of jquery you using? fancybox seems quite old, maybe it's not compatible with the newer versions of jQuery?

Comment: do you have this error on `$.fancybox.close();` line?

Comment: @JanR jQuery version: jquery-1.4

Comment: @vladkras yes! I put it in success function, then console show **Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'is' of undefined**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've posted unpacked version of **jquery.fancybox-1.3.4.js**: https://gist.github.com/vladkras/008361d790668634db74 to figure out what's happening.

While your `close()` function fires, it seems to stop at line 926:

```
if (busy || wrap.is(':hidden')) {
```

where `wrap = $('<div id="fancybox-wrap"></div>')` is undefined according to you error. Try  to put `type: "iframe"` to your fancybox options:

```
$("a.edit").fancybox({
    type: "iframe"
});
```

to let it now, that it has `parent`

**UPD** Also, are you sure you need that intermediate file `showForm.php`? It turns out that you make two ajax requests

```
index.php ----------> showForm.php ------------> process.php
           fancybox                     ajax
```

I think you can modify whole process:

1. recieve element fom db with ajax
2. create form with values on fly
3. show your form with fancybox
4. send changed data back
5. `$.fancybox.close()` on success

Comment: I follow your way to put **type: "iframe"**
and success function **parent.$.fancybox.close();**
but, console still show me error **Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'close' of undefined**

Comment: @Gondola what about parent.jQuery.fancybox.close()? Did you include fancybox in your showForm.php file?

Comment: yes,when I create a  test fancybox(with open and close event), it also can work~
ok, thanks alot, your explanation it's so clear!  
that solution I will try